# Fair coin tosses simulation and Law of Large Numbers

Tags: simulation, law-of-large-numbers

My question is related with a simulation Professor John Guttag did in the 15th lecture of the course MIT Opencourseware "Introduction to C.S."
The program simulates multiple **fair coin** tosses experiments. It sets multiple values for n, the number of tosses in each experiment and for each n, it repeats the experiment m times to infer some values (m is fixed for every n).

The number of tosses n is set to be powers of two, from $2^{k_{min}}$ to $2^{k{max}}$ so n is growing as the simulation progress.

**For each n**, the experiment is performed **m** times. In each of the m times, the number of Heads $H$ and Tails $T = n - H$ is stored and then the average (over the m repetitions) of $\frac{H}{T}$ and $|H -T|$ is computed, so we have an $\frac{H}{T}$ and $|H-T|$ average for each n.

For me it is very surprising that Guttang considers quite obvious that as **n** grows the fraction $\frac{H}{T}$ converges to 1 and that $|H-T|$ grows kind of linear with n.

I consider this far from obvious if you try to prove it mathematically.

Using random variables, by definition $H$ is a Binomail random variable $H \text{~}  Bin(n,\frac{1}{2})$

So by the **Law of Large Numbers** we know that the average computed over the $m$ repetitions tends to the expected value of $H$, $E[H] = np = \frac{n}{2}$ as m tends to infinity. 
I think that Prof Guttag assumes it is obvious that the ratio $\frac{H}{T}$ tends to one because $H$ tends to $\frac{n}{2}$ and so does $T$ (which is correct) and this seems to imply that $\frac{H}{T}$ tends to $\frac{\frac{n}{2}}{\frac{n}{2}} = 1$

This reasoning for me is not correct. In general $E[\frac{H}{T}] \neq \frac{E[H]}{E[T]}$. In this case in fact, $E[\frac{H}{T}] = E[\frac{H}{n-H}] =  \infty$ because the denominator can be zero with a probability equal $(\frac{1}{2})^n$. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Also, I think it is more "obvious" to think that $|H-T|$ tends to zero instead of thinking that grows with n. In fact, if m is large enough, $E[H-T] = E[2H - N] = 0  ~~\forall n$. I know that $E[|H-T|] \gt E[H-T]$ but not easy to see that it has to grow with n, any proof about this?

I would appreciate any comment if I am wrong about anything or if you have seen the Prof Gutag lecture and I have not understood it correctly.

Lecture 15th URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqZBqoZgL7k&index=21&list=PLB2BE3D6CA77BB8F7

Minute 15th show the graphs about the computed averages.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this slightly different way of framing it easier to deal with:

1. The difference in the proportion of heads and the proportion of tails indeed converges to 0.
2. $|H-T| = |H-(n-H)| = |2H-n| = 2|H-\frac{n}{2}|$. Even though $E(H)=\frac{n}{2}$, the typical distance of $H$ from its mean does not shrink and $n$ grows larger; in fact the distribution of $H$ becomes more spread out. For $n=2m$, the mean deviation of a binomial is $m{2m\choose m} 2^{-2m}$, which for large $m$ approaches $\sqrt{\frac{m}{\pi}}=\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}}$.

   At $n=100$, the exact mean deviation is $50\cdot {100\choose 50} 2^{-100}\approx 3.98$ while the large-$n$ approximation is $\sqrt{\frac{100}{2\pi}}\approx 3.99$.

   For large $n$ the mean deviation is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ ($\approx 0.8$) of the standard deviation; it's often easier to work from that since most people remember the standard deviation of a binomial and the scaling factor isn't hard to remember (or derive).

(I'll try to come back to the issue of $\frac{H}{T}$ in the original as soon as time permits)